# MethodError when trying to get a row from an Arrow Dataframe in Julia

Tags: julia, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[image]

I am taking a CSV file, converting it to Parquet and then sending it to Arrow. There is a reason why I am doing it like this. My goal is to get access to the information in row `"Algeria"`. This is my code:

```
df = CSV.read("temp.csv", DataFrame)
write_parquet("data_file.parquet", df)
df = DataFrame(read_parquet("data_file.parquet"))
Arrow.write("data_file.arrow", df)
df = DataFrame(Arrow.Table("data_file.arrow"))

dates = names(df)[5:end]
countries = unique(df[:, :"Country/Region"])

algeria = df[df."Country/Region" .== "Algeria", 4:end]
# Print(sum(eachcol(algeria)))
Print(Statistics.mean(eachcol(algeria)))
```

But the last part, which tries to retrieve the data from Arrow, throws this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching +(::Float64, ::String)

Closest candidates are:

+(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...) at operators.jl:538

+(::Float64, !Matched::Float64) at float.jl:401

+(!Matched::ChainRulesCore.One, ::Any) at /home/onur/.julia/packages/ChainRulesCore/7d1hl/src/differential_arithmetic.jl:94
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I get when I type in "Algeria" to the REPL

[image]

**Update:** Implementation of Gabriel's suggestion:

```
begin
    algeria = df[df."Country/Region" .== "Algeria", 4:end]
    
    for i = 1:size(algeria, 2)
        if eltype(algeria[!, i]) == String
            algeria[!, i] = parse.(Float64, algeria[!, i])
        end
    end
    
    Statistics.mean(eachcol(algeria))
end
```

This is the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching +(::Float64, ::String)

Closest candidates are:

+(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...) at operators.jl:538

+(::Float64, !Matched::Float64) at float.jl:401

+(!Matched::ChainRulesCore.One, ::Any) at /home/onur/.julia/packages/ChainRulesCore/7d1hl/src/differential_arithmetic.jl:94
```

Comment: Please remove the `begin` `end` blocks which are specific for Pluto and make it unnecessary hard for others to read your code.

Comment: Can you show us what is output when you type `algeria` into the REPL?

Comment: @GabrielHassler Check the edits

Comment: @oo92 Sorry for not being more clear, I was hoping to see what the type of each column in `algeria` is, which is usually output in the REPL (although apparently not in your particular editor). For `mean` to work, all elements in `algeria` should be of type `Float64`. Try this: `all(eltype.(df[!, i] for i = 1:size(df, 2)) .== Float64)` to see if it returns `true`. If not, figure out which columns are of the wrong type with `findall(eltype.(df[!, i] for i = 1:size(df, 2)) .!= Float64)` and use some version of `parse(x, Float64)` to convert them to the right type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to vectorize `mean`, please see the code below:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=1.5:1:3.5)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      1.5
   2 │     2      2.5
   3 │     3      3.5

julia> Statistics.mean.(eachcol(df))
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 2.5
```

Comment: Sure but that's not what I'm stuck with

Comment: You wrote "the last chunk" and this was the code there and it was incorrect with regard to vectorization. Perhaps you could in that case do some MWE to show more clearly what you need :-)

Comment: This is what is throwing the error mentioned: `algeria = df[df."Country/Region" .== "Algeria", 4:end]`

Comment: There is no addition (`+`) here involved. Maybe the commented out line was the reason?

Comment: Nope. Just removed that and makes no difference.

Comment: Btw. Your code doesn't make much of a different. Turns out it is my `Print(Statistics.mean(eachcol(algeria)))` that was throwing the error. I was trying to calculate the mean of all values in Algeria but I was getting the error above.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to say anything more from my side without a MWE. You can calculate means for rows by writing: `mean(Matrix(df),dims=2)`

Comment: Why are you using df? That's the entire dataframe. I am only trying to calculate a single row from that df

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like one of the columns in `algeria` contains strings rather than floating point numbers.

Try doing this before calculating the mean:

```
for i = 1:size(algeria, 2)
    if eltype(algeria[!, i]) == String
        algeria[!, i] = parse.(Float64, algeria[!, i])
    end
end
```

Comment: Check the edits. I tried to implement your logic and I got the same error.

Comment: have you tried the `findall(eltype.(df[!, i] for i = 1:size(df, 2)) .!= Float64)` to see if there are columns of the wrong type? Ultimately, `mean` is trying to add a `Float64` to a `String`, so there must a a `String` somewhere.

Comment: It just returns a list of integers from 1 to n where n is the size of the row